# Stabilizer and Orbit of Groups

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Consider $G = <(123),(45)> \subseteq S_5$.

What is the stabilizer of $4$, $G_4$, and the orbit of $4$, $G(4)$?

Workings:

The stabilizer of $x$ is the set of permutations that fix $x$

$G_4 = \{e, (123), (132), (125), (152), (235), (253), (12), (13), (15), (23), (25), (35)\}$

The orbit of $x$ is the set of permutations that permutes the elements of $x$.

$G(4) = \{4,5\}$

I'm not sure If I am right. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you are asking about the stabiliser and the orbit of $4$ in $G$, not in $S_5$. Do you know the order of $G$ and do you think that e.g. (125) is an element of $G$?

Comment: The orbit of $4$ is not a set of permutations, it is the subset of possible values in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ that $4$ may be sent to by elements of $G$.

Comment: It only makes sense to talk about the stabilizer and orbit for elements in a group $G$ when G is *acting* on some set. We need to know which set $G$ is acting on here in order to help answer your question.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov The order of $G$ is 20. And I think that $(34)(125)$ is an element of $G$

Comment: No, $|G|$ can't be $20$ as it is generated by two commuting elements $(123)$ and $(45)$ of orders $3$ and $2$ respectively.

Comment: Oh I thought $G$ was taking $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and splitting it up so that there is a group of order $3$ and a group of order $2$. Would $G = \{e, (123),(45),(123)(45),(132),(132)(45)\}$ and $|G| = 6$

Comment: Yes, $|G|=6$, and the list is correct. Can you now fix your calculation of stabiliser?

Comment: $G_4 = \{e,(123),(132)\}$

Comment: Yes, correct :-) Please remember that when you speak of stabiliser/orbit, you need to say in which group, and, if not obvious, under which action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sigma = (1\ 2\ 3)(4\ 5) \in S_5$.

It is evident that $G = \{e,\sigma,\sigma^2,\sigma^3,\sigma^4,\sigma^5\}$ and that $|\sigma| = 6$ (to cancel both cycles we need a common multiple of $2$ and $3$, and $6$ is the smallest such).

Your calculation of $G_4 = \{e,\sigma^2,\sigma^4\}$ is indeed correct ($\sigma^2 = (1\ 3\ 2)$ which fixes $4$, and thus any power of $\sigma^2$ fixes $4$), and $\sigma(4) = 5 \neq 4$, so since $\langle \sigma^2\rangle$ is maximal in $G$ (that is, there is no subgroup $H$ with $\langle \sigma^2\rangle \subset H \subset G$), we know $G_4 = \langle \sigma^2\rangle$.

Since $\sigma(4) = 5$, it is clear $5$ is in the orbit of $4$. On the other hand, it is not hard to see that $\sigma^k(\{4,5\}) = \{4,5\}$, since the odd powers of $\sigma$ permute $4$ and $5$, and the even powers fix them. Hence $G(4) = \{4,5\}$.